# URLConnection Still need Internet Permission Which should be by default

Tags: android

I want to update my app, I was using the old Appache Http Client, but since it is not recommended any more I'm going to use the new URLHTTPConnection class.

My question is still I have to add internet permissions to the manifest file, if I am using the new function knowing that Google removed the need to ask permission for internet as "most apps need it anyways nowadays" in their latest version, and how will that effect on users that still have no updated versions on their mobile devices?

Comment: Keep in mind that the new permissions only apply to API 23. So if you support versions earlier than that, they'll still need to have the old permissions in the manifest.

Comment: Also Google could decide to ask users again over a given Internet permission or even allow denying it in the future - which is not very likely, but it could happen, requiring you to declare that permission

Comment: I know that you are asking something else, but check volley or retrofit for that job. You will see a big difference on the speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely you have to add the internet permissions in your manifest, at least for now

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

not all devices are up to date.

They removed the need for the users to be prompted about it. You still need the `<uses-permission>` element.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, that is a good point, They removed the need for the users to be prompted about it. You still need the <uses-permission> element.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is still I have to add internet permissions to the manifest file,

Yes.

> Google removed the need to ask permission for internet

They removed the need for *the users to be prompted* about it. You still need the `<uses-permission>` element.